# Spring MVC always apply @Valid for all mappings for particular parameter object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Let's say I would like to validate incoming ID parameter for all my RESTful methods (>50).

As an example I have:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public
@ResponseBody
Metadata getMetadata(
        @PathVariable("id") Long id,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    return metadataService.get(id);
}
```

I would like to reject all requests if id < 1. As a solution I've implemented:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public
@ResponseBody
Metadata getMetadata(
        @Valid Id id,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    return metadataService.get(id.asLong());
}

public class Id {

@Min(1)
@NotNull
private Long id;

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long asLong() {
    return id;
}

}
```

But now I have to implicitly put @Valid annotation for each and every method for Id argument, which seems quite redundant . Is there a way to tell Spring that if there's an Id object as an incoming parameter it should always be @Valid. Without putting annotation each time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've ended up with solution like this:

```
public class CustomModelAttributeMethodProcessor extends ModelAttributeMethodProcessor {

public CustomModelAttributeMethodProcessor(boolean annotationNotRequired) {
    super(annotationNotRequired);
}

@Override
protected void bindRequestParameters(final WebDataBinder binder, final NativeWebRequest request) {
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest = request.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
    ((ServletRequestDataBinder) binder).bind(servletRequest);
}

@Override
protected void validateIfApplicable(final WebDataBinder binder, final MethodParameter parameter) {
    if (binder.getTarget().getClass().equals(Id.class)) {
        binder.validate();
        return;
    }

    super.validateIfApplicable(binder, parameter);
}
```

}

And configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        argumentResolvers.add(new CustomModelAttributeMethodProcessor(true));
    }
}
```

A bit overhead to check class of each and every incoming parameter, but works as expected. Now @Valid annotation can be omitted as validation performs by custom processor.